# It says "syntax error, insert 'VariableDeclarator'"

Tags: java, class, object

I am very new to programming and have started java this week. I am learning about object-orientation. Here is my problem:

```
public class Person
{
  int age = 0;
  String name = "John Doe";

  void display{
   System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old. ");
  }

}


public class Driver
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   Person mark = new Person();
    mark.age = 25;
    mark.name = "Mark";
   display;
  }


}
```

But it keeps saying

> syntax error, insert 'VariableDeclarator'

Comment: you cannot have more than one *public* class in the same `*.java` file

Comment: A method signature needs parenthesis `()` even though it doesn't take parameters `void display()` . You also need the parenthesis when you call it. `display();`

Comment: `display` method should have parenthesis `display()` in declaration and call

Comment: It is better to learn basic syntax first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow the instructions of your IDE.
2. the method `display` is part of the class `Person` and must have the correct syntax(visibility - return type - name - parameters).
3. you have to call the display method from the created `Person` object `mark`. Otherwise the method would not be resolvable for the compiler.
4. And last but not least... you have to create your own class for Person because two public classes are not possible in one source file or you have to reduce the visibility of the Driver class.

   ```
   package de.db.ri.as.gleisansagen.evaluator;

   public class Person {

     int age = 0;
     String name = "John Doe";

     void display() {

       System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old. ");
     }
   }

   class Driver {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Person mark = new Person();

   mark.age = 25;
   mark.name = "Mark";
   mark.display();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: It turns out i forgot to call the method display from "Person" (i.e mark.display();). Thankfully i didn't include 2 pubic classes in a single source file. It now works, but can i ask, do you see anything else "wrong" or could be improved with my code. Stuff like maybe its layout or anything

Answer (score -2):

Dont'code your own syntax program first learn java syntax then start coding
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/

```
public class Person {

    int age = 0;
    String name = "John Doe";

    void display() {

        System.out.println(name + " is " + age + " years old. ");
    }

}

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person mark = new Person();

        mark.age = 25;
        mark.name = "Mark";
        mark.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Answers that consist only of code, without any kind of explanation, aren't really what Stack Overflow is for.